# How to convert a registry key to an Image

Tags: c#

I need to get the current wallpaper and display it in a picturebox.
Now from what I understand, One of the ways to get the wallpaper is by doing the following:

```
RegistryKey UserWallpaper = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Control Panel\\Desktop", false);
```

How would I go about converting this to an Image so that i can display it in a PictureBox?

Comment: Presumably the registry value is a path and name of a file that you can then load as you would any other picture file.

Comment: So i would be able to use Image.FromFile?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Never mind I just tried that, Did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// get the registry-key
RegistryKey wp = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Control Panel\\Desktop", false);

// get the wallpaper filename
string sFileName = (string)wp.GetValue("Wallpaper");

// finally load the image into picture box
pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(sFileName);
```

Comment: Thanks! I did the same thing with ToString and it didnt work? But this works great! Much obliged!

Comment: Do you happen to know how I can get 2 different wallpapers If I am using a dual monitor display?

Comment: As far as I know you can't have two different wallpapers on a dual monitor display. I guess you could fake it though by merging the two different images into one, positioning them side by side in the appropriate resolution and then set the background to "Tile". I think they would then span across both displays, and you would seemingly have two separate pictures on the screens.

Answer (score 1):

The answer can already be found in another post since the value of the registry key is a file path

[Loading PictureBox Image from resource file with path (Part 3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17193825/loading-picturebox-image-from-resource-file-with-path-part-3)

Comment: pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(UserWallpaper.ToString() + ".bmp");
did not work... I also tried without the bmp

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Control Panel\\Desktop", false);
string wallpaper = key.GetValue("Wallpaper").ToString();
PictureBox pbox = new PictureBox();
pbox.Image = new Bitmap(wallpaper);
this.Controls.Add(pbox);
```