# Image in Windows Forms DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a Form with a DataGridView. The DataGridView's source is BindingList
Here's the Tiger class:

```
  public class Tiger
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Weight { get; set; }
    public DateTime Born { get; set; }
    public String Picture { get; set; }

    public Tiger(string name, int weight, DateTime born)
    {
        Name = name;
        Weight = weight;
        Born = born;
        Picture = "D:\\Dropbox\\Uni\\NET\\tigers";
    }
}
```

I want the Picture column to show the Image with URI in the Picture field, not the string. How can I implement it?

Comment: use ItemTemplate for that column; add Image tag and bind the source property to the actual picture path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that, create a column type Image in your datagridview and a `byte[]` property in your tiger class.

In your constructor, you read the image as a `byte[]` and set the property.

Use this `byte[]` property for the Image column in your datagridview

Answer (score 1):

maybe this code could help you:

```
        FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(@"Images\a.bmp", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read); 
pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(fs);

  fs.Close();
```

show this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17193825/loading-picturebox-image-from-resource-file-with-path-part-3)

good luck