# C# Windows Forms - How to programmatically set image preview for file folder (VSTO 2010)

Tags: c#, image, winforms, outlook, vsto

***Windows Forms - VSTO - Outlook***

**Background** - I am creating a digital archive add-in for Office where the user can search the database for the client (whom the document belongs to) and it will save the file to the appropriate folder(s) based on the nature of the file. So far this is working for Word as planned but I am now using Outlook which has more to consider (attachments, message body, etc.).

I have got it working so far that the attachments are saved into a temporary folder (which is emptied each time the windows form closes) ready to be sorted and I can obtain information about sender/subject/email body. The list of attachments is set out into a CheckedListBox

**Current Problem** - When a user is looking to archive an attachment (a lot of documents/scanned documents will come up), images will be confusing as they may be necessary or entirely unimportant so I wish to preview the images.

I am trying to get it so on the event of

```
private void chkAttachments_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

The image shows in `picAttachPreview` (PictureBox) as a preview of that file. This will be taking the image from `tempfolder` (`@"c:\temp\DigitalArchive"`).

I understand this is wrong but I am trying to set the source for the image shown on screen on that SelectedValueChanged event.

**My [Incorrect] Code** -

```
if(chkAttachments.Text.Contains(".jpg"))
        {
            var selectedImage = chkAttachments.SelectedValue.ToString();
            picAttachPreview.Image = tempfolder + @"\" + selectedImage; //(A)
        }
```

The `(A)` line is the issue and although I understand why, I don't know how to resolve it. The filepath is constructed with `tempfolder` and `selectedImage` (e.g. ScannedDoc.jpg) but the file path type is String but `picAttachPreview` is System.Drawing.Image so I assume I am looking at the wrong property of `picAttachPreview` to set the source of the image.

Any help or guidance will be immensely appreciated. Thank you.

(Also if you know of any good way I can set the same nature of preview for documents/PDF then I will be immensely grateful)

**Edit** Although the link solves part of my problem, there is an issue with `chkAttachments.SelectedValue.ToString()` which I answered below. (If anyone can advise me on the site etiquette for this situation. Do I delete the question or leave it with the answer I found so that people can find the solution to the same problem in future? Thank you)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loading PictureBox Image from resource file with path (Part 3)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17193825/loading-picturebox-image-from-resource-file-with-path-part-3)

Answer (score 0):

After some playing around, I found another problem (`chkAttachment.Text` works whereas `.SelectedValue.ToString()` does not.

Also the issue with the string to image format is resolved by prefixing the path with `Image.FromFile(`

So the correct way of changing the image upon selection is:

```
if(chkAttachments.Text.Contains(".jpg"))
        {
            var selectedImage = chkAttachments.Text;
            picAttachPreview.Image = Image.FromFile(tempfolder + @"\" + selectedImage);
        }
```

Comment: You may also consider using `Path.Combine()` to concatenate file directory and name to let .Net care about path delimiters for you: `Path.Combine(tempfolder, selectedImage)`

Comment: Don't use `Image.FromFile`, instead use `Image.FromStream`.